# Positioning widgets relatively

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `Positioned` widget nested in `Stack` widget and giving it the values right and bottom.

It worked nicely until I tried it on other screens with different sizes as I should've expected.

After Googling and stackoverflow-ing all the answers I've found advise to calculate the position depending on the device screen `width` and `height`.
I'm wondering if there is any way to position a widget relatively to its parent or to the stack widget - something like `position: relative`; in CSS -

```dart
  Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.touch_app,
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
                      right: 110.0,
                      bottom: 300.0,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Chart(occData),
                      onTap: _setDetailedView,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Media Query](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be `align`

```
Container(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              child: Text("Comment")
                          ),
                        ),
```

or

```
Container(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment(x, y), // <-- from 0 to 1, ex. 0.5, 0.5
                              child: Text("Comment")
                          ),
                        ),
```

you can align stuff in a `Stack` like:

```
Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Align(
                                alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0.3),
                                child: Text("Comment: $comment")
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```